# How to merge records using apex class?

Tags: apex, map

I have a **Purchase** related list under a Custom Object. This related list has all the details of the purchases made Like "Name", "Amount","Purchase Date" etc..

This related list has a Custom button **Upload**. Once records are approved,when  users clicks on the button, all the records will get updated to other Custom Object related list on the same Account layout.

So here I am able to insert every record in to the related.  I want to summarize them instead of showing all records. For eg: In the Purchase related list if it has 4 records with same **Name**    - ABC and Amount=300. Once the user **upload**. Only one record with ABC should get inserted with Amount 1200 .

Is it possible ?

Here is the part of code:

```
public ID AccId {get;set;}
public Purchase__c pur{get;set;}
//constructor
public className(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){
    AccId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
}
public PageReference addPurchase(){
    List<ApprovedData__c> apd = new List<ApprovedData__c>();

    List<Purchase__c> plist = [Select Id, Name,Amount__c,PurchaseDate__c,Company__c from Purchase__c where Account__C=:AccId];

    for(Purchase__c pur: plist){

        ApprovedData__c ap=new ApprovedData__c();
        ap.PName__c=pur.Name;
        ap.pAmount__c=pur.Amount__c;

        apd.add(ap);
    }


    insert apd;
}
else{
    ApexPages.Message errormsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'NO DATA FOUND');
    ApexPages.addMessage(errormsg);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: And how would you roll up `PurchaseDate__c` for records whose name is the same?

Comment: @AdrianLarson The Purchase related list Names will be same. Sorry for adding purchase date,that is old code. I updated my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you simply use a `Map<String, Decimal>` to store the results and convert that to a `List<ApprovedData__c>` at the end.

```
Map<String, Decimal> amounts = new Map<String, Decimal>();
for (Purchase__c purchase : purchases)
{
    if (!amounts.containsKey(purchase.Name))
        amounts.put(purchase.Name, purchase.Amount__c);
    else
        amounts.put(purchase.Name, amounts.get(purchase.Name) + purchase.Amount__c);
}

List<ApprovedData__c> records = new List<ApprovedData__c>();
for (String name : amounts.keySet())
    records.add(new ApprovedData__c(PName__c=name, PAmount__c=amounts.get(name));
insert records;
```

You should also look into [proper error handling](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling).